# Evaluating cost of sql query

Tags: sql, database

I was recently this question asked in an interview:

Suppose I have a sql query like

```
select A.a
from A JOIN B on A.b=B.c
```

Now the normal and **efficient way** in this case **is to first filter out the records from A and B based on the join condition and then do the join**.

The interviewer asked me to **give a scenario**(Not just the selection given above but anything else) **where the efficient way will be to first do the join and then select**.

I couldn't think of any such operator or scenario at that time and couldn't answer it and even now I am not able to think of it.Can anyone tell me any such scenario?

**UPDATE:** The above query is just an example to explain the normal execution process. The answer does not and will surely not be just a select operation but will include some other operation like Union, intersection etc. The interviewer wanted to know tht other condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the cost of filtering is higher than the cost of the join predicate, it may be more efficient to evaluate `join` criteria before a `where`:

```
create table Users (id int, name nvarchar(255));
create table Comments (userid int, commentText nvarchar(max));

create index IX_Comments_Users on Comments (userid);

select c.*
from Comments c
inner join Users u on c.userid = u.id
where u.name = 'foobar' and c.commentText like '%f%'
```

Although I am just guessing (and badly, at that), the query plan would hopefully get the results from `Users` and do an index seek on `Comments`, a rid lookup, then do the `like` at the very end.

However, on modern database platforms, you don't have to think about it: the optimizer will use statistics to estimate the number of rows, and usually pick the most efficient query plan.  The only time in which I have had to explicitly tune a query to evaluate `where` clauses first was when dealing with a linked server for which the optimizer had no schema information.

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver 'linkedServer','SQL Server';

create table big_table (id int, userid int, ... wide table too ...);

-- this produced a query plan on SQL Server 2008 which did the join, then a filter
-- I think I solved it by doing a TOP(int.max) hack or a remote join... don't remember
select *
from big_table b
inner join [linkedServer].someDb.dbo.small_table s on b.id = s.id
where s.someOtherColumn = 'a'
```

I emphasize oncemore, however, that what you write in the query has no relevance to how the query gets executed.  SQL Server and friends can be frighteningly brilliant in the optimizations they can do.  For example, your condition may not even get evaluated at execution time if there is an indexed view with the same criteria — the same can be said for a filtered index.

Learn to read query plans, love query plans, and respond to these questions with "When the query plan generated is sub-optimal, and the performance is causing an issue".  Any other methodology with SQL is mystical thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Theses comments are based on Oracle and SQL Server. It would help to put a specific database in as a tag since the answer to this kind of question is probably database specific.

The query planner decides whether records will be filtered before or after the join unless you use subtables and things like that to confuse it.

The only reason that I can think of that a cost based optimiser would want to filter *after* a join is if it required the output of an outer join to evaluate something, or a predicate required a calc from across both tables

In your sample query it will do some kind of scan on both tables then some kind of join.

It can't/won't 'prefilter' records *before* the join, based on the join predicate because it would have to do some kind of hash/join beforehand anyway to identify the records, and that is twice the work, and a cost based optimiser won't choose twice the work.

If you look at a query plan... it always does a join before a SELECT as SELECT is last in the plan. So you may wish to clarify your second statement.

I think your interviewer must be alluding to something else but I'm not sure what.

The fact is an optimiser always tries to reduce the records going into the join operator (by filtering), so the join operator has less work to do.

Comment: Agreed his second statement does not make sense. Another thing I dont see any filters in this query. The `ON` "filter" statement is part of the `JOIN` a `WHERE` statement would be a filter unless I am missing something.

Comment: @ElectricLlama I know that for above simple query of SELECT the system will always do a filtering before join.What the interviewer wanted to know is to give any operation(like union,intersection etc) or scenario where system will do join before filtering.

Comment: The interviewer did not wanted to think of only as SELECT.He gave this example to make me understand the normal case of execution.He wanted to know any other operation where the opposite will be more efficient